# Target SVG path to the middle of rect element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, rect

I'm using D3 library to draw an interconnected graph of elements. My nodes are `circles` and `rects` connected by oriented line `path`s.

My problem is that lines pointing to `rects` element have an ugly visualisation because the line ends on the top-left corner of the rect rather then the center of it (as it does for circles).

How can I make path lines target the center of both `circles` elements and `rect` elements?

---

Code for definition of `defs` arrow heads:

```
svg.append('defs')
  .append('marker')
  .attr('id', 'arrow')
  .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
  .attr('refX', 17) // As far as I understood this provides the distance from the end of the path line.
  .attr('refY', -0.1)
  .attr('markerWidth', 6)
  .attr('markerHeight', 6)
  .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .attr('fill', function() {
    return 'red';
  })
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5');
```

Definition of oriented links:

```
let links = svg.selectAll('.link')
  .data(data.links)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('id', function (d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.2)
  .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)')
  .attr('stroke', function() {
    return 'blue';
  })
  .style('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Definition of squares

```
let squares = svg.selectAll('.square')
  .data(data.squares, function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .enter().append('g')
  .call(dragger)
  .attr('class', 'square')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer');

squares.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 10)
  .attr('height', 10)
  .attr('fill', function (d) {
    return '#fff';
  })
  .style('opacity', 0.1)
  .style('stroke', function() {
    return '#555';
  })
  .style('stroke-width', '2');
```

---

In following screenshot you can see how it behaves. Circles and rects have a low opacity to show up the issue with the path target.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Added `tick` function definition and usage.

```
simulation
  .nodes(data.nodes)
  .on('tick', _tick);

simulation
  .force('link')
  .distance(80)
  .links(data.links);

simulation.alpha(1).restart();

function _tick() {
  links.attr('d', function(d) {
    let dx = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    let dy = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    let dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return ('M' + d.source.x + ',' + d.source.y + 
            'A' + dr + ',' + dr + ' 0 0,1 ' + d.target.x + ',' + d.target.y);
  });
  circles.attr('transform', function (d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  });
  squares.attr('transform', function (d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Can you translate the square? If you can translate it half of the square
   width.
2. Can you find the end of that path on square it like the x2,y2? Plus that half of your square width,.

**"hope this inspired you"**

```
squares.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 10)
  .attr('height', 10)
  .attr("transform", "translate(-5,0)")
  .attr('fill', function (d) {
    return '#fff';
  })
```

Comment: Translating the square didn't occur to my mind. I've tried with the parameters you proposed but they're not the right one, using `.attr("transform", "translate(-5,-5)")` instead it looks better (consider that every item is draggable, hence I had to translate both axis). I'm waiting for further answers otherwise I'll accept yours.

Comment: PS: You don't need to concatenate the strings and numbers as in `"translate("+(-5)+", "+0+")"`, just write the numbers in the string as in `"translate(-5,-5)"`.

Comment: i usually using dynamic parameter that its how, anyway did it work?

Comment: Yeah, I imagined ;) Yes, it did work with parameters `-5,-5`. Anyway I'd like to wait for other answers before accepting this because, as I've said in the question, I'd like to know if there's a way to make the `path` point the center of the `rect` rather than its corner and I feel like translating the `rect` is a kind of workaround. :)

Answer (score 3):

What you have right now is the expected behaviour. In a force simulation (I suppose you're running a force simulation), the `tick` function changes the `x` and `y` properties of the datum object, and you can use them the way you want.

As you didn't shared your `tick` function, I suppose that you are updating the rectangles' `x` and `y` position like this:

```
squares.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x
}).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y
});
```

If that in fact is correct, the top-left corner of the rectangles correspond to `d.x` and `d.y` coordinates. And, since you're using the same properties to draw the path, the paths will go from one top-left corner to the other.

This is easy to show, have a look at this demo:

```js
var width = 200;
var height = 200;

var rectSide = 40;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = [{
  name: "foo",
  color: "blue"
}, {
  name: "bar",
  color: "green"
}, {
  name: "baz",
  color: "red"
}];

var links = [{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 1
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 2
}];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(100))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var node = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", rectSide)
  .attr("height", rectSide)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color
  });

var link = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#222")
  .style("stroke-width", 2);

simulation.nodes(nodes);
simulation.force("link")
  .links(links);

simulation.on("tick", function() {

  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })

  node.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x
  }).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

**Solution**: You can either move the rectangles or the paths.

As your question specifically asks about the *paths*, the solution is simple: add half-width and half-height to the target and source coordinates:

```
link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x + rectangleWidth / 2;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y + rectangleHeight / 2;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x + rectangleWidth / 2;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y + rectangleHeight / 2;
    })
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var width = 200;
var height = 200;

var rectSide = 40;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = [{
  name: "foo",
  color: "blue"
}, {
  name: "bar",
  color: "green"
}, {
  name: "baz",
  color: "red"
}];

var links = [{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 1
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 2
}];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(100))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var node = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", rectSide)
  .attr("height", rectSide)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color
  });

var link = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#222")
  .style("stroke-width", 2);

simulation.nodes(nodes);
simulation.force("link")
  .links(links);

simulation.on("tick", function() {

  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x + rectSide / 2;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y + rectSide / 2;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x + rectSide / 2;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y + rectSide / 2;
    })

  node.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x
  }).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Gerardo, thanks for the detailed answer, you were supposing right I'm using a _forceSimulation_. As for the `tick` function it is slightly different, I've added it to the question. As you can see I use `d` _attr_ rather than `x1,x2,y1,y2` do you think it is still feasible?

Comment: Sure, just add half-width and half-height to `d.target.x` and `d.target.y`.

Comment: Sorry, you mean as the last two values concatenated in the final string or when computing `dx` and `dy`? Thanks :)

Comment: I figured and declared `let targetX = d.target.x + (10/2);` (same for `y`) and used them.. The problem now is that paths are correctly set to target the square center but when paths are targeting a circle they are now out of the circles border.

Comment: Both. And don't forget the parenthesis, because you're concatenating strings and numbers.

Comment: Well, for solving the circles problem the best idea is you creating a [MCVE].

Comment: And please, when you have a minimum running code, post it as a *new question*, otherwise I'll be the only one seeing it.

Comment: OK, nice suggestion. I'll link it here when done so you can see it if you care to help me with the new question :)